# Querying across multiple elasticsearch types

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to fetch documents present in multiple types (type1 AND type2 AND type3...) in Elastic Search 5.0 . I know searching across multiple types is possible by using multiple types like type1,type2 in URL and by also filtering the _type field. But all these conditions are OR (type1 OR type2). How do I achieve the AND condition?

Here are two documents in my ES,

```
{
   "_index":"cust_58e8700034fa4e368590fb1396e2641c",
   "_type":"unique-fp-domains",
   "_id":"n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c_258b3ad1a11aba282f35908662bdc5432d68fd96bf3ca90013dcdd5764331399",
   "_version":2,
   "_score":1,
   "_source":{
      "mg_timestamp":1579866709096,
      "violated-directive":"connect-src",
      "fp-hash":"258b3ad1a11aba282f35908662bdc5432d68fd96bf3ca90013dcdd5764331399",
      "time":1579866709096,
      "scan-id":"n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c",
      "blocked-uri":"play.sundaysky.com"
   }
}


{
   "_index":"cust_58e8700034fa4e368590fb1396e2641c",
   "_type":"tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain",
   "_id":"AW_XY4P4kmprPQ28bTUb",
   "_version":1,
   "_score":1,
   "_source":{
      "tagged-domain":"sundaysky.com",
      "tag-guidance":"FP",
      "additional-tag-metadata-isbase64-encoded":"eyJ0b3RhbC1hbGV4YS1tYXRjaGVzIjoyMzh9",
      "project-id":2,
      "fp-hash":"258b3ad1a11aba282f35908662bdc5432d68fd96bf3ca90013dcdd5764331399",
      "scan-id":"n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c",
   }
}
```

I want to fetch the documents from the same index from the given 2 types with `"scan-id":"n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c"`

I tried this,

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_type": {
                    "value": "tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "scan-id": {
                    "value": "n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_type": {
                    "value": "unique-fp-domains"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "scan-id": {
                    "value": "n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: can you share some samples(query, documents, expected and actual result).

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back, I have added sample documents and requirement in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch is not good in joining different collections of documents, but in your case you might be able to solve your issue with [`parent-child`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-parent-field.html) relationship.

#### How to query many index types together in an AND fashion?

In case when you have a [**one-to-many** relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)) you can model it with [`parent-child`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-parent-field.html). Let's suppose that type `unique-fp-domains` is "parent" type and `scan-id` field is a unique identifier. Let's also suppose that `tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain` is a "child" and every document of type `tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain` refers to exactly 1 document in `unique-fp-domains`.

Then we should create the Elasticsearch mapping in the following way:

```
PUT /cust_58
{
  "mappings": {
    "unique-fp-domains": {},
    "tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "unique-fp-domains" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And insert the documents like this:

```
# "parent"
PUT /cust_58/unique-fp-domains/n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c
{
    "mg_timestamp": 1579866709096,
    "violated-directive": "connect-src",
    "fp-hash": "258b3ad1a11aba282f35908662bdc5432d68fd96bf3ca90013dcdd5764331399",
    "time": 1579866709096,
    "scan-id": "n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c",
    "blocked-uri": "play.sundaysky.com"
}

# "child"
POST /cust_58/tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain?parent=n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c
{
    "tagged-domain": "sundaysky.com",
    "tag-guidance": "FP",
    "additional-tag-metadata-isbase64-encoded": "eyJ0b3RhbC1hbGV4YS1tYXRjaGVzIjoyMzh9",
    "project-id": 2,
    "fp-hash": "258b3ad1a11aba282f35908662bdc5432d68fd96bf3ca90013dcdd5764331399",
    "scan-id": "n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c"
}
```

Now we will be able to query for parent objects having any child associated with it == join on parent ID, which is we forced to be `scan-id` by providing the `_id` of the document manually.

The query will use [`has_child`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) and will look like this:

```
POST /cust_58/unique-fp-domains/_search
{
    "query": {
        "has_child": {
            "type": "tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain",
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we use [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-inner-hits.html) to tell Elasticsearch to retrieve the matched "child" documents.

The output would look like:

```
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "cust_58",
        "_type": "unique-fp-domains",
        "_id": "n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "mg_timestamp": 1579866709096,
          "violated-directive": "connect-src",
...
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_type": "tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain",
                  "_id": "AW_xhfnnIzWDkoWd1czA",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_routing": "n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c",
                  "_parent": "n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c",
                  "_source": {
                    "tagged-domain": "sundaysky.com",
...
                  }
```

#### What are the downsides of using `parent-child`?

- the parent ID should be unique
- join is only on parent ID
- some [performance overhead](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-has-child-query.html):

  > If you care about query performance you should not use this query.
- to enable parent-child one will have to change the mappings and reindex the existing data

#### Other important things to consider

In Elasticsearch 6, types [have been removed](https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch). The good news are that already starting from Elasticsearch 5 one can use [`join` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/parent-join.html).

In general, Elasticsearch is not very good to manage relations between objects, but [there are few ways to deal with them](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Nikolay. Apologies for replying so late. I agree with your answer. One thing though, the above parent-child data modelling doesn't work for me. But I agree there should have been some different data model for elastic search for my data. Are there any references for data modelling in elastic search. I am used to thinking in relational database terms. Any guidelines will be quite helpful.

Comment: @z3r0 Glad I could help. I think that a good starting point is the [Modeling your data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/modeling-your-data.html) chapter of the ES Definitive Guide, it's a bit outdated (based on ES 2) but covers core concepts pretty well. Subsection "Handling relationships" talks about how to model relations in ES (~= the same as I [linked above](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch)).

Answer (score 1):

I think this query will figure out your problem;

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "terms": {
          "_type": "tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain"
        }
      },
      {
        "terms": {
          "_type": "unique-fp-domains"
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter": [
      {
        "scan-id": {
          "_type": "n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "(_type : unique-fp-domains OR tag-alexa-top1k-using-csp-tld-domain) AND (scan-id : n_d4dbba7309a94503b25eca735078f17c)
            }
    }

Answer (score -1):

you could use a msearch. This can combine multiple searches. You can find more information about this at their documentation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Comment: How do I perform and condition between the independent results of the requests?

Comment: Please consider adding an example to your answer.